# 12.04 /var directory default user:group ownership

Tags: 12.04, permissions, default

I'm pretty sure I recursively messed up the default `/var` user:group ownerships. I've tried to restore them to the best of my ability by searching.  Specifically, I'm worried about `/var/lib`.  Currently, mine looks like the below.  If there's a kind soul out there who would please post their `/var/lib` so I can see if I'm missing something.

```
drwxr-xr-x  4 root          root          4096 Jul  3  2012 AccountsService
drwxr-xr-x  2 root          root          4096 Mar 13  2012 acpi-support
drwxr-xr-x  2 root          root          4096 Nov 13  2011 alien
drwxr-xr-x  2 root          root          4096 Apr 30 01:14 alsa
drwxr-xr-x  6 root          root          4096 May 30 17:23 apt
drwxr-xr-x  2 root          root          4096 May 30 07:36 apt-xapian-index
drwxr-xr-x  2 root          root          4096 Jul  3  2012 aspell
drwxr-xr-x  2 avahi-autoipd avahi-autoipd 4096 Jul  3  2012 avahi-autoipd
drwxr-xr-x  2 root          root          4096 Apr 30 01:13 belocs
drwxr-xr-x  2 root          root          4096 May  8 08:42 binfmts
drwxr-xr-x  5 boinc         boinc         4096 May  7 01:27 boinc-client
drwxr-xr-x  2 colord        colord        4096 Apr 30 00:23 colord
drwxr-xr-x  2 root          root          4096 Apr 30 00:23 dbus
drwxr-xr-x  3 root          root          4096 Jul  3  2012 dell-recovery
drwxr-xr-x  2 root          root          4096 May 13 19:01 dhcp
drwxr-xr-x  5 root          root          4096 Apr 30 00:19 dictionaries-common
drwxr-xr-x  4 root          root          4096 May 30 17:05 dkms
drwxr-xr-x  5 root          root          4096 Jul  3  2012 doc-base
drwxr-xr-x  7 root          root          4096 May 30 17:23 dpkg
drwxr-xr-x  7 root          root          4096 Jul  3  2012 gconf
drwxr-xr-x  4 root          root          4096 Jul  3  2012 ghostscript
drwxr-xr-x  2 root          root          4096 Apr 30 01:06 hp
drwxr-xr-x  2 root          root          4096 May 30 17:23 initramfs-tools
drwxr-xr-x  2 root          root          4096 Apr 14  2012 initscripts
drwxr-xr-x  2 root          root          4096 Apr 14  2012 insserv
drwxr-xr-x  2 root          root          4096 May 12 01:50 iptraf
drwxr-xr-x  3 root          root          4096 Jul  3  2012 libreoffice
drwxrwsr-x  2 libuuid       libuuid       4096 Jul  3  2012 libuuid
drwxr-x--- 10 lightdm       lightdm       4096 May 30 17:51 lightdm
drwxr-xr-x  2 root          root          4096 Apr 30 00:31 localechooser
drwxr-xr-x  3 root          root          4096 Jul  3  2012 locales
drwxr-xr-x  2 root          root          4096 May 30 07:36 logrotate
drwxr-xr-x  2 root          root          4096 Oct 23  2012 lsb
drwxr-xr-x  2 root          root          4096 Apr 19  2012 misc
drwxr-xr-x  2 root          root          4096 May 30 07:36 mlocate
drwx------  6 mysql         mysql         4096 May 30 17:51 mysql
drwxr-xr-x  2 root          root          4096 May 30 17:51 NetworkManager
drwxr-xr-x  2 root          root          4096 Mar  6  2012 ntpdate
drwxr-xr-x  2 root          root          4096 Apr 30 01:03 nvidia-common
drwxr-xr-x  2 root          root          4096 May 30 17:23 os-prober
drwxr-xr-x  2 root          root          4096 May  8 08:42 pam
drwx-wx-wt  2 root          root          4096 Mar 11 07:44 php5
drwxr-xr-x  3 root          root          4096 May  7 19:20 phpmyadmin
drwxr-xr-x  2 root          root          4096 Apr 30 00:23 plymouth
drwx------  3 root          root          4096 Jul  3  2012 polkit-1
drwxr-xr-x  2 pulse         pulse         4096 May 31  2012 pulseaudio
drwxr-xr-x  2 root          root          4096 Apr 30 11:30 pycentral
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root          root            18 Apr 30 00:19 python-support -> /usr/lib/pymodules
drwxr-xr-x  2 root          root          4096 Apr 30 00:32 register-module
drwxr-xr-x  2 root          root          4096 Apr 30 01:14 rfkill
drwxr-xr-x  2 root          root          4096 Jan 17 09:56 rpm
drwxr-xr-x  2 root          root          4096 Jun  8  2012 samba
drwxr-xr-x  2 root          root          4096 Jul  3  2012 sgml-base
drwxr-xr-x  2 root          root          4096 May 22  2012 snmp
drwx------  3 root          root          4096 Jan  1  1985 sudo
drwxr-xr-x  2 root          root          4096 Apr 17  2012 synaptic
drwxr-xr-x  2 root          root          4096 Apr 30 00:32 ubiquity
-rw-r--r--  1 root          root           174 Jul  3  2012 ubuntu_dist_channel
drwxr-xr-x  3 root          root          4096 May 22 18:48 ucf
drwxr-xr-x  2 root          root          4096 May 30 17:52 udisks
drwxr-xr-x  2 root          root          4096 Apr 30 00:58 update-manager
drwxr-xr-x  4 root          root          4096 Apr 30 00:58 update-notifier
drwxr-xr-x  2 root          root          4096 May 23 18:02 update-rc.d
drwxr-xr-x  2 root          root          4096 May 21 18:44 upower
drwxr-xr-x  2 root          root          4096 May 30 17:51 urandom
drwxr-xr-x  3 root          root          4096 May 30 17:26 ureadahead
drwxr-xr-x  2 root          root          4096 Mar  7  2012 usb_modeswitch
drwxr-xr-x  2 root          root          4096 Jul  3  2012 usbutils
drwxr-xr-x  3 root          root          4096 Jul  3  2012 vim
drwxr-xr-x  2 root          root          4096 Jul  3  2012 xfonts
drwxr-xr-x  2 root          root          4096 Apr 30 01:37 xkb
drwxr-xr-x  2 root          root          4096 Apr 30 18:42 xml-core
```

Answer (score 0):

### 12.04

(for 13.04 read below)

```
drwxr-xr-x  4 root          root          4096 Oct 14  2011 AccountsService
drwxr-xr-x  2 root          root          4096 Nov 21  2010 acpi-support
drwxr-xr-x  2 root          root          4096 Feb 27 08:12 acroplugin
drwxr-xr-x  2 root          root          4096 Jul 15  2011 alsa
drwxr-xr-x  6 root          root          4096 May 30 08:47 apt
drwxr-xr-x  2 root          root          4096 May 30 08:02 apt-xapian-index
drwxr-xr-x  2 root          root          4096 Oct 14  2011 aspell
drwxr-xr-x  2 avahi-autoipd avahi-autoipd 4096 Apr 25  2011 avahi-autoipd
drwxr-xr-x  2 root          root          4096 Feb  6 09:34 belocs
drwxr-xr-x  2 root          root          4096 May  8 08:32 binfmts
drwxr-xr-x  2 colord        colord        4096 Oct 14  2011 colord
drwxr-xr-x  2 root          root          4096 Apr 25  2011 computer-janitor
drwxr-xr-x  2 root          root          4096 Jun 17  2011 dbus
drwxr-xr-x  4 root          root          4096 Sep  4  2012 defoma
drwxr-xr-x  2 root          root          4096 May 21 22:37 dhcp
drwxr-xr-x  5 root          root          4096 Apr 25  2011 dictionaries-common
drwxr-xr-x  3 root          root          4096 May  9 10:02 dkms
drwxr-xr-x  5 root          root          4096 Oct 14  2011 doc-base
drwxr-xr-x  7 root          root          4096 May 30 08:47 dpkg
drwxr-xr-x  3 root          root          4096 Sep  4  2012 dropbox
drwxr-xr-x  2 root          root          4096 Feb 15  2012 flashplugin-installer
drwxr-xr-x  7 root          root          4096 Oct 14  2011 gconf
drwxr-x--- 11 gdm           gdm           4096 May  2 09:17 gdm
drwxr-xr-x  4 root          root          4096 Apr 25  2011 ghostscript
drwxr-xr-x  2 root          root          4096 Sep  4  2012 hp
drwxr-xr-x  2 root          root          4096 May 24 11:09 initramfs-tools
drwxr-xr-x  2 root          root          4096 Mar 28  2011 initscripts
drwxr-xr-x  2 root          root          4096 Mar 28  2011 insserv
drwxr-xr-x  3 root          root          4096 Sep  4  2012 libreoffice
drwxrwsr-x  2 libuuid       libuuid       4096 Apr 25  2011 libuuid
drwxr-x---  9 lightdm       lightdm       4096 May 21 22:38 lightdm
drwxr-xr-x  2 root          root          4096 Sep  4  2012 lintian
drwxr-xr-x  3 root          root          4096 Apr 25  2011 locales
drwxr-xr-x  2 root          root          4096 May 30 08:01 logrotate
drwxr-xr-x  2 root          root          4096 Apr 21  2011 misc
drwxr-xr-x  2 root          root          4096 May 30 08:02 mlocate
drwxr-xr-x  2 root          root          4096 May 21 22:38 NetworkManager
drwxr-xr-x  4 statd         root          4096 Jan  4 23:44 nfs
drwxr-xr-x  2 root          root          4096 Mar 10  2011 ntpdate
drwxr-xr-x  2 root          root          4096 Oct  3  2012 nvidia-common
drwxr-xr-x  2 root          root          4096 May 16 08:36 os-prober
drwxr-xr-x  2 root          root          4096 May  7 09:55 pam
drwxr-xr-x  2 root          root          4096 Jun 17  2011 plymouth
drwx------  3 root          root          4096 Apr 25  2011 polkit-1
drwxr-xr-x  2 root          root          4096 Apr 11  2011 pulseaudio
drwxr-xr-x  2 root          root          4096 May  9 10:01 pycentral
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root          root            18 Sep  4  2012 python-support -> /usr/lib/pymodules
drwxr-xr-x  2 root          root          4096 Sep  4  2012 rfkill
drwxr-xr-x  5 root          root          4096 Sep  4  2012 samba
drwxr-xr-x  2 root          root          4096 Apr 25  2011 sgml-base
drwxr-xr-x  2 root          root          4096 Feb  2  2011 snmp
drwx------  4 root          root          4096 Jan  1  1985 sudo
drwxr-xr-x  2 root          root          4096 Apr  6  2011 synaptic
drwxr-xr-x  5 root          root          4096 Feb  8  2012 tex-common
drwxr-xr-x  5 root          root          4096 Sep  4  2012 texmf
drwxr-xr-x  3 root          root          4096 Jun 17  2011 ubiquity
drwxr-xr-x  3 root          root          4096 May 23 07:52 ucf
drwxr-xr-x  2 root          root          4096 May 21 22:38 udisks
drwxr-xr-x  2 root          root          4096 Sep  5  2012 update-manager
drwxr-xr-x  4 root          root          4096 Feb  3 09:49 update-notifier
drwxr-xr-x  2 root          root          4096 May  9 10:01 update-rc.d
drwxr-xr-x  2 root          root          4096 Apr 14  2011 upower
drwxr-xr-x  2 root          root          4096 May 21 22:37 urandom
drwxr-xr-x  3 root          root          4096 May 23 07:52 ureadahead
drwxr-xr-x  2 root          root          4096 Mar 22  2011 usb_modeswitch
drwxr-xr-x  2 root          root          4096 Sep  4  2012 usbutils
drwxr-xr-x  3 root          root          4096 Apr 25  2011 vim
drwxr-xr-x  2 root          root          4096 Apr 25  2011 xfonts
drwxr-xr-x  2 root          root          4096 Sep  4  2012 xkb
drwxr-xr-x  2 root          root          4096 Sep  4  2012 xml-core
```

The only difference I can spot is

```
pulse pulse pulseaudio # you
root root pulseaudio # me
```

---

### 13.04

On raring I get this situation (which is very similar to my 12.04 one)

```
total 272
drwxr-xr-x 4 root          root          4096 Apr 24 10:03 AccountsService
drwxr-xr-x 2 root          root          4096 Oct  9  2012 acpi-support
drwxr-xr-x 2 root          root          4096 May 21 15:20 alsa
drwxr-xr-x 6 root          root          4096 May 30 12:31 apt
drwxr-xr-x 2 root          root          4096 May 30 07:54 apt-xapian-index
drwxr-xr-x 2 root          root          4096 Apr 24 10:03 aspell
drwxr-xr-x 2 avahi-autoipd avahi-autoipd 4096 Apr 24 10:04 avahi-autoipd
drwxr-xr-x 2 root          root          4096 May 21 15:07 belocs
drwxr-xr-x 2 root          root          4096 May 22 23:36 binfmts
drwxr-xr-x 3 colord        colord        4096 May 21 15:16 colord
drwxr-xr-x 2 root          root          4096 May 21 15:16 dbus
drwxr-xr-x 2 root          root          4096 Apr 24 10:02 dhcp
drwxr-xr-x 5 root          root          4096 May 21 15:08 dictionaries-common
drwxr-xr-x 3 root          root          4096 May 22 11:06 dkms
drwxr-xr-x 5 root          root          4096 Apr 24 10:03 doc-base
drwxr-xr-x 7 root          root          4096 May 30 12:31 dpkg
drwxr-xr-x 2 root          root          4096 May 14 09:36 flashplugin-installer
drwxr-xr-x 5 root          root          4096 Apr 24 10:03 gconf
drwxr-xr-x 4 root          root          4096 Apr 24 10:03 ghostscript
drwxr-xr-x 2 root          root          4096 Mar  8 23:46 hp
drwxr-xr-x 2 root          root          4096 May 21 15:19 initramfs-tools
drwxr-xr-x 2 root          root          4096 Jan 30 04:58 initscripts
drwxr-xr-x 2 root          root          4096 Jan 30 04:58 insserv
drwxr-xr-x 3 root          root          4096 Apr 24 10:03 libreoffice
drwxrwsr-x 2 libuuid       libuuid       4096 Apr 24 10:02 libuuid
drwxr-xr-x 3 root          root          4096 May 22 23:36 libxml-sax-perl
drwxr-x--- 7 lightdm       lightdm       4096 May 27 09:42 lightdm
drwxr-xr-x 2 root          root          4096 Mar 18 11:16 lintian
drwxr-xr-x 3 root          root          4096 Apr 24 10:02 locales
drwxr-xr-x 2 root          root          4096 May 30 07:54 logrotate
drwxr-xr-x 2 root          root          4096 Apr 19 02:03 misc
drwxr-xr-x 2 root          root          4096 May 30 07:54 mlocate
drwxr-xr-x 2 root          root          4096 May 27 02:17 NetworkManager
drwxr-xr-x 4 statd         nogroup       4096 May 22 13:57 nfs
drwxr-xr-x 2 root          root          4096 Apr  4 15:25 ntpdate
drwxr-xr-x 2 root          root          4096 May 21 15:19 os-prober
drwxr-xr-x 2 root          root          4096 May 21 15:09 pam
drwxr-xr-x 2 root          root          4096 May 21 15:16 plymouth
drwxr-xr-x 2 root          root          4096 May 22 10:20 pm-utils
drwx------ 3 root          root          4096 Apr 24 10:03 polkit-1
drwxr-xr-x 2 root          root          4096 Apr 18 06:33 pulseaudio
drwxr-xr-x 2 root          root          4096 May 22 10:49 pycentral
drwxr-xr-x 2 root          root          4096 Apr 24 10:04 python
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root          root            18 May 22 10:47 python-support -> /usr/lib/pymodules
drwxr-xr-x 2 root          root          4096 May 21 15:20 rfkill
drwxr-xr-x 2 root          root          4096 Nov 26  2012 samba
drwxr-xr-x 2 root          root          4096 May 22 10:49 sgml-base
drwxr-xr-x 2 root          root          4096 Dec  6 00:10 snmp
drwx------ 3 root          root          4096 Jan  1  1985 sudo
drwxr-xr-x 5 root          root          4096 May 22 10:52 tex-common
drwxr-xr-x 9 root          root          4096 May 28 10:15 texmf
drwxr-xr-x 3 root          root          4096 May 21 15:08 ubiquity
drwxr-xr-x 2 root          root          4096 May 21 15:16 ubuntu-drivers-common
drwxr-xr-x 2 root          root          4096 May 21 15:16 ubuntu-release-upgrader
drwxr-xr-x 3 root          root          4096 May 22 23:36 ucf
drwxr-xr-x 2 root          root          4096 Mar 13 08:14 udisks
drwx------ 2 root          root          4096 May 23 09:16 udisks2
drwxr-xr-x 2 root          root          4096 May 22 21:26 update-manager
drwxr-xr-x 4 root          root          4096 May 21 15:16 update-notifier
drwxr-xr-x 2 root          root          4096 May 22 10:53 update-rc.d
drwxr-xr-x 2 root          root          4096 Mar 19 23:07 upower
drwxr-xr-x 2 root          root          4096 May 27 02:17 urandom
drwxr-xr-x 3 root          root          4096 May 30 11:41 ureadahead
drwxr-xr-x 2 root          root          4096 Oct  8  2012 usb_modeswitch
drwxr-xr-x 2 root          root          4096 Apr 24 10:03 usbutils
drwxr-xr-x 3 root          root          4096 Apr 24 10:02 vim
drwxr-xr-x 2 root          root          4096 Apr 24 10:05 xfonts
drwxr-xr-x 2 root          root          4096 May 21 15:16 xkb
drwxr-xr-x 2 root          root          4096 May 22 10:49 xml-core
```

The only disagreement from a little awk and sort of our two outputs in terms of ownership is

```
pulse pulse pulseaudio
root root pulseaudio
```

Although, of course there are some libraries that we don't appear to share.

Comment: Thanks a million! I wasn't sure about pulse; I'll set it back to root. I really appreciate your help.